# Does ionic apps cache depends on the device browser (on devices)

Tags: ionic-framework

I have this doubt. I use PouchDB to save the data I show in my app so I can have an "offline" mode, but I am not saving the images from this data, just referencing thru URLs in `img` tags.

What I don't know is: If the users empties their browsers cache (webview Android / Safari iOS) the downloaded images showed in the app will be erased too? or Ionic Apps had their own cache?